# Which clients accept DHCP option 42 to configure their NTP servers?

Tags: dhcp, ntp

From what I can tell based on observations of my own OS X 10.8.5 machine, and the information in "[Windows clients not using NTP server provided via DHCP](https://superuser.com/questions/147248/windows-clients-not-using-ntp-server-provided-via-dhcp)," neither OS X nor Windows 7 are able to auto-configure their NTP servers. So, which DHCP clients do this by default, or after special configuration?

Comment: This basically boils down to a product recommendation/list request, which are considered off-topic.

Comment: @techie007 I don't know more than 2 dhcp clients (+ the OS X that OP mentions), so I doubt is about software recommendations.

Comment: @Braiam Replace "DHCP Client" with any other piece of software, and then replace "uses option 42" with any feature you might want to see in that piece of software. And (IMHO) you have a regular, off-topic product request.  Example: "Photoshop doesn't do X. What other photo editors do?" is not acceptable.

Comment: @techie007 He's asking almost at the end if he needs to make a configuration to his current clients (W7 and OSX) to accept this option specified in the DHCP implementation, or if he needs another client to get this functionality, which is not software recommendation and a very valid question that I'm surprised that it hasn't be asked somewhere else.

Comment: @techie007 this is most definitely not a soft-rec question as DHCP is a protocol.  Suggesting that DHCP is software would mean we would also have to close TCP/IP, HTTP, FTP, etc,. and that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Kronos A DHCP "client" is a piece of software. I think I'm reading a different question than you guys. ;)  "neither OS X nor Windows 7 are able to auto-configure their NTP servers" is NOT asking how to configure them, it's stating that they don't support it (which is true). "So, which DHCP clients do this?" -- User has already realized/stated that the W7 and OSX DHCP clients don't support this, so he's asking which (other) DHCP clients DO support it.

Comment: @techie007 unless my understand is extremely misconstrued, DHCP is a protocol and not a piece of software.  Yes software is used to interpret and run the protocol, but it's not like regular software where you can just uninstall and reinstall, or install a 3rd party version of it.  It's very much integrated into the OS.

Comment: @KronoS Yes, DHCP is a protocol (that's the P). A "DHCP client" (in this post's context) would be a piece of software interfacing with a "DHCP server", whether the client is integrated with the OS or not. As an aside, I don't think the DHCP client in Windows (for example) is as integrated as you think. It's just a service, it could probably be replaced relatively easily if you found or [wrote your own](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363344(v=vs.85).aspx) compatible DHCP client.

Comment: @techie007 no matter how we 'classify' this question, I think we both agree that it's not a good fit for SU in it's  current condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [ISC DHCP client](https://www.isc.org/downloads/dhcp/) (which is used in almost any Linux distribution) and its variants accept the NTP field. There isn't another well known/universal client that accepts this value.

If I have to guess about why OSX nor Windows supports this option, I would say is due the various flaws that the base DHCP protocol has, like no Authentification Method, since mal intentioned DHCP servers could change your systems clocks, etc. Also, there aren't lots of DHCP clients out there (I only know Windows and ISC-based clients), so that leave little (or no) options where to pick.

Maybe OS X allows you to install another DHCP client, Windows isn't so easy, but you could be sure that Linux does.

- http://www.internetnews.com/dev-news/article.php/1570721
- http://althing.cs.dartmouth.edu/local/dhcp_flaws.html